# Neural Networks - Back Propagation and Perceptrons

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, perceptron

While studying about neural networks (still on basics - not Deep Learning etc.,) two questions came on my mind.

- What is the reason for replacing the hard limiter function in the nodes of the multilayer perceptrons (MLPs) with smoother ones?
- Does the Back propagation algorithm always find the best possible solution for the classification problem at hand?

Answer (score 1):

- Smooth functions has well-defined derivatives and suitable for back-propagation algorithm. There are also non-smooth ones, such as ReLU, widely used for this purpose; however, they're piecewise differentiable, while the hard-limiter function is not.
- Back-propagation algorithm doesn't find the best solution. It is actually [gradient descent](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gradient_descent), and it finds you a local optimum. Sometimes, this might be the global optimum, but frequently it is not due to the sheer size of search space.And, not all local minima are bad.